# Are there any records of Foreign investments or Foreign Direct Investments (FDI) in history from pre-medieval or medieval period?

Tags: middle-ages, economy

A foreign direct investment (FDI) is an investment in the form of a controlling ownership in a business in one country by an entity based in another country. If we look at the articles about the history of FDI or Foreign investments over the web, we find that authors are only covering the part of the history of FDI     from the last two decades. For e.g. in this PDF [**" Concept and Historical Background of Foreign Direct Investment"**](https://shodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in/bitstream/10603/16539/9/09_chapter%201.pdf) the first phase starts from 1870-1914.

Now we know the empires like the Roman empire did build roads or religious structures in regions they conquered, this could be an example of Foreign investment. But that was in the plan of their territorial expansion and keep those regions under their rule and was not part of Mutual Collaboration.

Also I am not asking about FDI  or Foreign investments made during the Colonial period by British, Spanish, Portuguese multinational enterprises etc. Like The East India Company and such. But records of earlier forms of FDI  mostly from the medieval period or earlier.

Do we have any records of any individual kings, nations, guilds making an  FDI / Mutual collaborative projects in another region or country, not as a conqueror but for mutual business benefits? like improving the roads,  construction works, shipbuilding, construction of ports etc. in treaties from the **pre-medieval or medieval era. ?**

Comment: "in a business" - the notion of FDI relies on the existence of a business as a legally recognized entity in the target country.  I don't think such entities exist in the medieval period.  Investment in roads is investment in infrastructure, not FDI - I am not sure that we're using FDI to refer to the same concept; could we document the terms a bit better?

Comment: Could you edit your question to clarify what you've looked into already, complete with links and references, and context if applicable? In particular, please let us know what you find missing or unclear about the Wikipedia entry on the topic, if one exists. This allows those who might want to answer to do so without needing to redo the work you've already done. You might find it helpful to review the site tour and Help Centre and, in particular, How to Ask.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Yes, we can change the label to trade investment in foreign lands or so. The missing part is most articles are starting the history of the topic from 19 th century. I am here not specifically asking about the modern term FDI , but to trace the history of investments in foreign lands for economic purposes. For e.g. this is one of the PDF article i read before asking the question - https://shodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in/bitstream/10603/16539/9/09_chapter%201.pdf

Comment: You might find some early examples of investments made by Venice in the aftermath of its rise during the crusades. Though even those could be construed as keeping important trade ports under Venetian influence -- and best I'm aware they weren't funded by the city proper. Also, a problem with your question is that in those days there wasn't much of a State in the modern sense to speak of.

Comment: Does the Church count as FDI in your question? basically because many monastic orders (or even the Vatican) work as a foreign country investing in another territory. Building a infraestructure of churches, monasteries, schools, etc.

Comment: @Santiago haha, spiritual investment. I think no .  But one can mention this as a secondary part of answer for sure.: -)

Comment: Please edit the information from the comments into the question - the question should contain all the information.

Comment: I have investigated the Hanseatic League's *kontors* or the Italian bankers *lombard credit* but neither seem to fit this question.

Comment: Would the Fugger's businesses count?  They were German but had invested and controlled mines all over Europe, such as Norway, Sweden, Hungary, and even the New World.

Comment: @ed.hank - Yes ,Yeah ,they are the match. They did established trade ties  with Peru and Chile and started mining ventures in Sweden and Norway and at various places. Go ahead  with the answer.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy Agree on your point that n those days there wasn't much of a State in the modern sense to speak of.And that is the reason i have added kings , guilds , individuals etc.

Comment: Santiago comment about religious orders is not as funny as it looks. This 'investment' would not be only a church. Monasteries would own land and serfs, transfer agricultural/water/food/archtectural technology around, and bring expert workers from outside (including the monks themselves).  Monasteries could improve the tech, productivity and trade value of their region, or at least occupy land that would be less productive otherwise. Cities were born around monasteries.